# PostgreSQL and hibernate Order by version number 1.1.1.1.1

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

My BDD is postgreSQL 9.1-901.jdbc4

My ORM is hibernate who works with spring boot 1.5.1 and spring data REST

I have a table with number version

```
1.1
1.3
1.2.1
1.3.12.4
1.5.10.3.5
```

I have 5 number max.

In my @respositoryRestResource

I tried this custom query :

```
@query("select v FROM version v ORDER By cidr(numberVersion)")
List<Version> findByversionOrderBYNumberVersion();
```

this custom query works just until 4 number.

I tried other custom query :

```
@query("select v FROM version v ORDER BY STRING_TO_ARRAY(numberVersion, '.')::int[] ASC")
List<Version> findByversionOrderBYNumberVersion();
```

I have an error  :

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:

SomeOne can help me ? please  I don't have other idea ...

I can't create a function in postgres.

Comment: I don't use obfuscation layers like Hibernate, but doesn't `@query` indicate a **HQL** query? If you want to use native Postgres functions you need to use a **native** query, not HQL

Comment: *Suggestion:* Don't ask the database or Hibernate to sort. Instead, sort the returned `List` in Java, using custom `Comparator`.

Comment: I tried to use native query this :
@query(value = "select v FROM version v ORDER BY STRING_TO_ARRAY(numberVersion, '.')::int[] ASC", nativeQuery=true)
List<Version> findByversionOrderBYNumberVersion();

I have this exception :

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [:int]

how can i excluse like param ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution ...

```
@query(value = "select * FROM version ORDER BY STRING_TO_ARRAY(numberVersion, '.')\\:\\:int[] ASC", nativeQuery=true) 
List<Version> findByversionOrderBYNumberVersion();
```

thank you for your help !